# How to take the select word from python code and printing in script shell after calling the script from python?

Tags: python, bash

I have the code python

```
import os
# put the words you want to match into a list
matching_words = ["apple", "pear", "car", "house"]

# get some text from the user 
user_string = input("Please enter some text:")

# loop over each word in matching_words and check if it is a substring of user_string
for word in matching_words:
    if word in user_string:
        print("\n{} is in the user string\n\n".format(word))
        os.system('/home/raed/Desktop/1.sh')
```

And I have this code in script

```
#! /bin/bash
########################
if [ "$2" = "pear" ]; then
    echo " This is '$2'"
elif [ "$2" = "apple" ]; then
    echo " This is '$2'"
else
    echo " This is '$2'"
exit 0
```

So If I choose any word from list of python code I need the script recognize and print it

I have got this error How to solve it ?!!

```
Please enter some text:apple

apple is in the user string


/home/raed/Desktop/1.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: does the file /home/Desktop/1.sh exist? you are not passing any param to your script

Comment: Sorry .. I have edit the question !!

Comment: the problem is in your bashscript you expect to get parameters (because of $2) but you don't give any param to your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your word as an argument in your python program.

Following is a snippet of code with some minor revisions to your program.

```
import os
# put the words you want to match into a list
matching_words = ["apple", "pear", "car", "house"]

# get some text from the user 
user_string = input("Please enter some text:")

# loop over each word in matching_words and check if it is a substring of user_string
for word in matching_words:
    if word in user_string:
        com = '/home/craig/Python_Programs/Script/1.sh ' + word
        print("\n{} is in the user string\n\n".format(word))
        os.system(com)
```

Also, in your bash script, you will want to check argument #1 ($1) in lieu of argument #2 ($2) as noted in the following tweaks to your script.

```
#! /bin/bash
########################
if [ "$1" = "pear" ]; then
    echo " This is '$1'"
elif [ "$1" = "apple" ]; then
    echo " This is '$1'"
else
    echo " This is '$1'"
exit 0

fi
```

Following is a sample of the output from my terminal.

```
Una:~/Python_Programs/Script$ python3 Script.py 
Please enter some text:apple

apple is in the user string


 This is 'apple'
Una:~/Python_Programs/Script$ python3 Script.py 
Please enter some text:pear

pear is in the user string


 This is 'pear'
```

I believe that will net you the results you are after.

Regards,